# Facebook Canvas app login doesnt't work

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-canvas

i have created a facebook app and it works well for new users if they start the app with the direct server link (https://www.mydomain.com/app/index.php) and use the login button.

But if they try to use the app within facebook (https://apps.facebook.com/myapp) as a canvas app(for the first time) then they see the "landing" page of my app and the log in button. But if they click on it, an errormessage appears, that the  content of the iframe couldn't be displayed.  If they start the app in a new tab, then the login process works. (see the error below, sorry it's german, maybe you are familiar with this type of error message?)

[image]

It would be desirable if the new user could use the login link in the canvas app.

How can this be achieved? My index.php looks like this: (i am using the facebook SDK)

```
<?php

  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {


      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get 404 not found when you wanna access from facebook ?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I was wrong with my "problem" description. I updated my starting post. It doesn't work for NEW users, who haven't granted the app the access token yet. If they click on "log in", an error message appears (see above).